# Disable webpage like js alert do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `custom dialog-box` for `confirmation` message it will appear correctly but the back view of page is clickable/enable so user can click anywhere i want to disable that back view.
Just like native `js` `alert, confirm box` do.
Following is image of js alert box in which all back view is not accessible how do i achieve this thing when i am using my custom boxes.
[image]

Comment: Check whether the custom dialog box widget has a _modal_ option.

Comment: If you're using jQuery Mobile, I know you can do it. [See here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0-beta.1/docs/pages/popup/index.html) with `data-dismissible="false"`.

Comment: bootbox alert would be great.. (http://bootboxjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
HTML:
<div id="alert-overlay-wrapper"></div>

CSS:
#alert-overlay {
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

Add the html div in the html of the custom alert box as well add the css.

This work as the overlay for the body.

The one thing you have take care is that the "z-index" of the custom alert box must be greater than 1000 as overlay z-index is 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [jQuery Alert](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/) or a similar plugin.

Logic: Create a div with lightbox like effect. The lightbox will cover the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

The best example of your situation is bootstrap modals [Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
Just see how twitter developers do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :-

Twitter boot strap modol box : [Modol Box](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)

jQuery Fancybox : [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

jquery Colorbox : [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/)